# Network Error when connecting to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

While I log in to SqlServer it is showing this error:

[image: Sql Server Error]

Comment: try pinging server ..

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see several areas:

1. Check that you have enable services SQL Browser
2. Check that you have some blocking on your Firewall. For example open cmd and check telnet IP_server_database oraz ping IP_server_database